# How to implement an algorithm to detect if a number has 2 consecutive digits?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to create a function that returns true if a number has consecutive digits or not,

example:

- if the input is 11, it will return true
- if the input is 21 it will return false
- if the input is 323 it will return false because even though we have 3 repeated, they are not consecutive

My solution right now is to transform the number into an array and loop through the number one by one, if the next number is equal to the current number then we just return true. But this has a complexity time of O(n) and I was wondering if anyone can come with a better solution.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted? Hard to imagine something better than `O(n)` for this purpose.

Comment: You obviously need to examine all the digits to check for identity, so you're unlikely to be able to go below o(n) with n = number of digits.

Comment: Your O(n) algorithm is the best time complexity you can get for this problem. Solutions involving regular expressions are just delegating the loop to the regex engine.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: for super long numbers like `2345674396539588934682364823553` and more... I think the regex would do only 10 iterations (see my answer). So it should be faster.

Comment: @louys wrong. Have you checked the implementation of the RegEx engine to back your claim? Or run any performance comparison? If not, stop guessing.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The regex engine still needs to scan the input string to find matches of the pattern. That loop is going to be O(n).

Answer (score 3):

There is an arguably better solution where you don't need to convert the number into a string or array of numbers/character. It works as follows:

1. Initialize a variable `curr` to `-1`.
2. Run a loop `while num > 0` and do the following:

- `next_curr = num % 10`
- `if next_curr == curr: return true`
- `curr = next_curr`
- `num = num / 10` (integer division)

3. If the loop completes, return false.

This is a one pass `O(log n)` time complexity algorithm where `n` is the input number. The space complexity is `O(1)`

Note that while your algorithm was also `O(log n)` time complexity, it did 2 passes, and had a space complexity of `O(log n)` too.

I haven't written JS for some time now, but here's a possible implementation of the above algorithm in JS:

```js
function sameAdjacentDigits(num) {
    // to deal with negative numbers and
    // avoid potential problems when using Math.floor later
    num = Math.abs(num)
    let curr = -1
    while (num > 0) {
        const nextCurr = num % 10
        if (nextCurr == curr) return true
        curr = nextCurr
        num = Math.floor(num / 10)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, is it possible to get some code with it, not sure if I understand what you mean but looks like it's not working

Comment: Please, read the code that I added to the answer. @PetyIalimijoroRakotoniaina

Comment: keep in mind this only works for integers, so really large numbers will not work: for example `sameAdjacentDigits(12345678901234567890)` will always give `true`, while other solutions here give `false`

Comment: @skara9 The OP converts a number to an array, so the initial input is a number, not a string.

Comment: to avoid false positives, perhaps you can throw an error if the number exceeds the integer limit

Comment: @skara9 I'm afraid your are going too far :-|

Comment: @skara9 IMHO this is the less naive answer so far.

Comment: If you're looping over the digits of the input, then n should be the length of the input, not its value. This algorithm is also O(n).

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes I was wondering about that, "`n` is the input number" sounds weird to me.

Comment: @misterwtf I'm aware, i don't disagree with the answer --- i was just pointing out a possible source of confusion as someone may run the func with `98765432109876543` and expect a `false`; safer to throw

Comment: While I agree that the algorithm presented is _better_, I disagree to the O(log n) thing. With that argument, you can "improve" every algorithm simply by changing what n means. Traditionally it refers to the length of a turing machine's band, and should be used in that way.

Comment: @JonasWilms My algorithm doesn't improve the time complexity. I specifically stated that OP's algorithm is also `O(log n)` where `n` is the input number. The improvement is an optimization. This is a one pass algorithm, OP's was a 2 pass one. In addition this algorithm improves the space complexity for whatever it's worth.

Comment: Maybe it was a bad idea on my part to change the definition of `n` compared to what OP defined it. This is how I have seen it more, to express the number of digits in terms of the number itself. Sorry if I created confusion about it.

Comment: I think I got it. `O(log n)` is right since `log n` is the number of digits, then I suppose the confusion comes from the name of the variable `n` since `O(log n)` is a naming convention in computer science. Writing "This is a one pass O(n) time complexity algorithm where n = log(x) is the number of digits of the input number x." is probably better. Am I right?

Comment: You are right @misterwtf your expression is much clearer.

Comment: @user1984 can you please explain the math fundamentals of this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use some regex, and then check what was found via the matcher

```js
numbers_match = /(00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)/;
numbers_match.match("11")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Thank you but about the time complexity, don't you think it's still O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to execute this is by using regex. Not sure what would be effectiveness of algorithm, but solution could be

`/(\d)\1/`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @Tschallacka's answer:

```js
let numbers = [11,21,323];

let result = numbers.map(n=>{
  let test = n.toString().match(/(00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)/);
  return test != null;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not sure about the time complexity of regex, I think it still has to loop to all of the strings to find the match right?

Comment: I'm am unsure how regex is performing the loop internally... But I assume it should loop only 10 times (for the ten possibilities). So on super long numbers, it should be faster than iterating all digits... Again, I am unsure about it.

Comment: I made an attempt to measure the execution time on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/abLXKqO?editors=0012) and... It looks like less than a millisecond even for a `BigInt`.